# Visual Composer Grid with do_action shortcode is not working

Tags: wordpress

I have visual composer which is packed with total theme. When I put the following grid short code in my page in the editor it works correctly.

[vc_basic_grid post_type="post_type" max_items="10" item="masonryGrid_SlideFromLeft" grid_id="vc_gid:1458178666639-80ebf3775500c87d35de078c3422fe96-10" taxonomies="555"]

However, when I call the exact same code using do_action it gives the following javascript error. I checked the html output and it is the same using do_action like putting the short code in editor.

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {'status':'Nothing found'}
>   s

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Same problem, looking for a solution

Comment: you are using do_shortcode() right ?

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can't output contents directly in your templates by using core shortcodes of VC like that.

### 1. Problem:

For security, besides nonce, VC uses `page_id` and `shortcode_id` to check AJAX request/respond data.

The `shortcode_id` is automatically generated by VC, you can not harcode it.

For example, this is the shortcode you see on admin editor screen:

`[vc_basic_grid post_type="post_type" max_items="10" item="masonryGrid_SlideFromLeft" grid_id="vc_gid:1458178666639-80ebf3775500c87d35de078c3422fe96-10" taxonomies="555"]`

Let say the page ID is 4269, this is the generated HTML code on front-end:

```
<!-- vc_grid start -->
<div class="vc_grid-container-wrapper vc_clearfix">
    <div class="vc_grid-container vc_clearfix wpb_content_element vc_masonry_grid" data-initial-loading-animation="zoomIn" data-vc-grid-settings="{"page_id":4269,"style":"all-masonry","action":"vc_get_vc_grid_data","shortcode_id":"1458178666639-80ebf3775500c87d35de078c3422fe96-10","tag":"vc_masonry_grid"}" data-vc-request="http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" data-vc-post-id="4269" data-vc-public-nonce="0641473b09">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- vc_grid end -->
```

Now, if `page_id` and `shortcode_id` don't match each other, `{'status':'Nothing found - $shorcode_id'}` will be throw out and no contents will be displayed.

You can find out more inside `vc_grid.min.js` file.

### 2. Solution:

- Generate a fake page with VC, then copy generated html code to your template file.
- [Create a template](https://vc.wpbakery.com/video-academy/use-templates-visual-composer/) with VC directly.
- Use [Shorcode Mapper](https://vc.wpbakery.com/video-academy/add-shortcodes-visual-composer-wordpress/) to create your own shorcode.

Comment: I am not sure If I understand your solution. In this case I am using the shortcode [vc_basic_grid] provided with the VC. I have done any change, but still get the error, then the error is that the page id (supose 4269) is because the generated id for the shortcode dont matches page id (like that one 1458178666639-80ebf3775500c87d35de078c3422fe96-10) ?? Is that my error or VC error?

Comment: It's your fault. When you copy the shorcode on admin editor screen, it's an incomplete shorcode. VC does another step, as i said, it's data verification.
To make it easy to understand: First, you create a fake page with **Backend Editor** of VC then view that page on front-end, look at HTML source code you will find out a block of code `<!-- vc_grid start --> ... <!-- vc_grid end -->`. Inside that code block, you will see `shorcode_id`, `page_id`, `nonce`... which you cannot copy and paste. That's the problem.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. Thats what I am doing, I enter the backend editor in a page (created some time ago). Using VC I add a row and the vc_grid component (graphically). Then I save and get this error. I am not copy poasting any text.

Comment: @ProgramadorAdagal So the error appears on admin screen console? It's weird! Because when you saved a page, only raw shortcode is saved. VC doesn't render anything until the page is called on front-end.

Comment: I am guessing my explanation wasn't very good, so sorry. I mean that, in admin panel, I use Backend Editor for composing the page, and, after saving, in **Frontend** throws that error. I didn`t change the shortcode or anything, just take the id it gives to me visually. That means VC is giving me a bad ID?

Comment: @ProgramadorAdagal Well, VC generates `shortcode_id` and `page_id` on front-end base on `vc_gid` in the shortcode and ID of the page which contains  the shorcode on back-end. VC doesn't give you anything which is out of you control.

I recommend you to update to the latest version, delete every shortcodes on that page and regenerate it.

Comment: I have the last version but support has ended. I will try your solution.

Comment: In my case, this was caused reliably by adding a certain vc element onto the same page alongside the grid element. I'm guessing the other el isn't properly closing it's query loop & wpquery reset. Didn't spend more time on it , but would recommend trying to remove other items on the page to make sure it's actually the grid causing it. Because the solution proposed here is definitely far deeper than I needed to go for this error.

Answer (score 1):

First you build a new page and add a grid post on it, 
then we get

> _vc_post_settings

post meta , and try to build a new one 
then update post meta data
now we can by pass VC Ajax security check 
in the following code "1513628284966-37b8c3ca-d8ec-1" is VC generated guid
you should change it to yours .

```
$meta = get_post_meta(1365,'_vc_post_settings');
 $settings = array();
 #$settings['vc_grid_id'] = $meta[0]['vc_grid_id'];
 $key = random_int(1513628284966,9513628284966);
 $settings['vc_grid_id']['shortcodes'][''.$key.'-37b8c3ca-d8ec-1'] = $meta[0]['vc_grid_id']['shortcodes']['1513628284966-37b8c3ca-d8ec-1'];
 $settings['vc_grid_id']['shortcodes'][''.$key.'-37b8c3ca-d8ec-1']['atts']['custom_query'] = "tag=shop";
 $settings['vc_grid_id']['shortcodes'][''.$key.'-37b8c3ca-d8ec-1']['atts']['grid_id'] = ''.$key.'-37b8c3ca-d8ec-1';
$n = add_post_meta(1365,'_vc_post_settings',$settings);


return do_shortcode("[vc_basic_grid post_type=\"custom\" show_filter=\"yes\" filter_style=\"dropdown\" item=\"5959\" grid_id=\"vc_gid:".$key."-37b8c3ca-d8ec-1\" filter_source=\"post_tag\" custom_query='tag=".$tag."']");
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved.
I had the same problems, with the Visual Composer Editor offered by WpBakery
https://wpbakery.com/
and after understanding the connection between the IDs of the block, and the ID of the Post, I put more attention to the settings of the Block.

There is infact one field called "**Element ID**", and here we have to put **our ID of the Post** we are editing.

In my case the Block was a block containing some Posts.

[image]

After saving, and viewing the page without the Editor, I was finally able to see the block, and not the message

```
{"status":"Nothing found"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this problem.
I modified the woocommerce category template and linked to the woocommerce_archive_description hook to add additional descriptions from some pages, for this I got their id, and then display the content.

```
echo do_shortcode($post->post_content);
```

The gallery(media grid) didn't work because there was a mismatch between the page id and the shortcode id. Therefore, the logical solution was to redefine the global variable $post to the $post of the page from which I get the content.

```
global $post;
$post = get_post( $id );
```

And it turns out that the post id matches.

After that, don't forget to return the normal $post value;

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

By the way - use this option to load custom styles for wpbakery elements.

```
echo '<style type="text/css" data-type="vc_shortcodes-custom-css">' . get_post_meta( $id, '_wpb_shortcodes_custom_css', true ) . '</style>';
```

The whole code

```
function extra_product_category_desc(){
    if( is_product_category() ){
        $id = get_term_meta (get_queried_object()->term_id, 'pageId', true);
        if($id !== ''){
            global $post;
            $post = get_post( $id );
            echo do_shortcode($post->post_content);
            echo '<style type="text/css" data-type="vc_shortcodes-custom-css">' . get_post_meta( $id, '_wpb_shortcodes_custom_css', true ) . '</style>';
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'extra_product_category_desc', 11 );
```

Answer (score -3):

You may also try with do_shortcode('');

Like

do_shortcode('[vc_basic_grid post_type="post_type" max_items="10" item="masonryGrid_SlideFromLeft" grid_id="vc_gid:1458178666639-80ebf3775500c87d35de078c3422fe96-10" taxonomies="555"]');

Best Regards,