# Visual Composer Masonry Grid doesn't work with do_shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, masonry, visual-composer

I am trying to run a simple do_shortcode using the following shortcode. I am trying to use it in a template page:

```
[vc_row]
[vc_column offset="vc_col-xs-12"]
[vc_empty_space]

[vc_masonry_grid post_type="custom" item="30085" grid_id="vc_gid:1501607642378-18d5e30a-9317-9" custom_query="post_status=publish&posts_per_page=-1"]

[vc_empty_space]
[/vc_column]
[/vc_row]
```

The problem is that the masonry grid works on a page but it doesn't work when I use do_shortcode. It renders but it keeps loading forever. Any ideas why?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Also did you have executed `do_shortcode` with `echo` before? And is the page header and footer included in the template file?

Comment: It doesn't show any errors in the console and I am using echo before do_shortcode. Thanks! :)

Comment: I found the same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36062447/visual-composer-grid-with-do-action-shortcode-is-not-working

Comment: Thanks man! I should search at stack overflow instead of just google.

Comment: No problem at all!